# How to prevent or detect - Error in XPath or condition causes unexpected behavior

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Before 'TestModel_05' the variable is missing. Therefore I will get an unexpect call of template2. How I can make it safer or how I will be able to detect this fault.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="model" as="xs:string">TestModel_04</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$model = 'TestModel_01' or $model = 'TestModel_02' or 'TestModel_05' or $model = 'TestModel_06'">
                <xsl:call-template name="template2"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#xa;&lt;!-- as expected no call of template2 --&gt;&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="template2">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#xa;&lt;!--    U N E X P E C T E D   call of   template2 --&gt;&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You will need to explain what you want to check in plain English. Your boolean `or` expression with one operand being a non-empty string like `'TestModel_05'` is always true.

Comment: The condition should test which model is actual used. I have not set the variable before. That was my mistake. Unfortunately, I have a lot of such conditions and I am looking for a solution to avoid such hard-to-find mistakes. In this case the condition is always fulfilled by the absence of the variable (because of the missing variable I will get an or expression with non-empty string which is always true) .

Comment: In XSLT 2 or 3 (which you seem to be using given the `as="xs:string"`) you can shorten your condition to `$model = ('TestModel_01', 'TestModel_02',  'TestModel_05' , 'TestModel_06')`. So there you only have to write the variable reference `$model` once. Does that help?  If not you might want to provide some more context, it is hard to imagine from that example what you want to achieve and how to simplify or improve it.

Comment: Your suggestion is working. Thanks. Suppose I need a solution in XSLT1 as well: I tried the example and it seems to work as well in XSLT1. But my XML editor has displayed an error message:   Error in expression $model = ('TestModel_01', 'TestModel_02', 'TestModel_05' , 'TestModel_06'): expected ")", found ","  - Therfore I am not sure that this will work also stable in XSLT1 in all cases.

Comment: In XSLT/XPath 1 it is difficult as it only has primitive string values but not sequences of strings. So unless you compare to some XML you load from another document and compare e.g. `$model = document('models.xml')/models/model` or take the effort to set up a variable with some similar structure (e.g. `<xsl:variable name="models"><models><model>TestModel_01</model><model>TestModel_02</model></models></xsl:variable>`) which you additionally convert to a node set with e.g. `$model = exsl:node-set($models)/models/model` you don't get an elegant comparison.

Comment: Some people in XSLT 1 also use e.g. `contains('|TestModel_01|TestModel_02|', concat('|', $model, '|')` but that is obviously far from being readable and manageable.